# SQL query: modified returned column value

Tags: sql

I don't understand how these work, could someone please explain these.

```
SELECT 
    P.ID, 
    P.CATEGORY_ID,
    TIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TIME) + 30) / 30 * 30, 0)
FROM 
    PRODUCTS P
WHERE 
    TIME >= CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 15, GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a tag for the database product you are using.

Comment: That won't work. You can't use `TIME` in the `WHERE` clause, because it doesn't exist yet, unless it's a column in `PRODUCTS` (in which case it will be overwritten by your `DATEADD()` function). In most modern DBMSes, the `WHERE` is processed before the `SELECT` and all columns in the `SELECT` are processed at the same time, so you can't use `TIME` in the `SELECT` either. Other than that, which part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Actually, `PRODUCTS.TIME` won't be "overwritten" because it's never added into the `SELECT`. This query would simply add a new column to the `SELECT` named `TIME`. It's still extremely confusing the intent, especially since `TIME` is referred to in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. I apologize for being so naive.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to leave a comment, but this may be much more text than a comment can hold. In breaking down what appears to be the intent of your query:

`,TIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TIME) + 30) / 30 * 30, 0)`

In this piece, the second `TIME` would refer to a `TIME` column in the `PRODUCTS` table, but would be overwritten when the `DATEADD()` function is assigned to the `TIME` value in the `SELECT`. That's kinda bad practice and confusing to overwrite actual column values like that in your query. `,TIME` shoudl be something different, like `,TIME2`.

Going from the inside of that statement out:

`DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,TIME)` >> Essentially, since a `date` in SQL is stored as a numeric number of minutes since the server's epoch (ie 1/1/2018 = 62062590 = minutes since 1/1/1900), this is calculating the difference in minutes since `TIME` and `epoch` or `0`. And `DATEDIFF()` returns an `integer`.

`DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,TIME) + 30` >> Since the `DATEDIFF()` function gave us an `integer` of minutes, this simply adds 30 to that number, giving us the equivalent of 30 minutes past `TIME`.

`(....) / 30 * 30` >> Then the weird math starts. I assume it is doing something to try to convert everything back to an `integer` or something.

`DATEADD(MINUTE, (....), 0)` >> Once again, we are just adding `0` minutes to the previously calculated `integer`. Since `DATEADD()` returns a `date` object, this is likely just converting everything back into a `date`.

`TIME = ......` >> Again, I think this is bad practice. Despite the name already have a special meaning in SQL, the query indicates that `TIME` is already a column in `PRODUCTS`. This is just creating a `TIME` column in the `SELECT` and assigning a value to it.

Then we move to the `WHERE` part of the query:

`WHERE TIME >= ...` >> This again indicates that `TIME` is a column in `PRODUCTS`. As I mentioned above, if `TIME` is supposed to be the value from the `SELECT`, it won't work since the `WHERE` is processed long before the `SELECT`.

`(DATEADD(DAY,-15,GETUTCDATE())` >> This is just taking the current UTC date (`GETUTCDATE()`) and subtracting 15 days from it.

The rest of it is just casting the date object back into a `datetime` object.

Then it's checking to see if `TIME` is more recent than 15 days before today.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, i was enlightened when you said "WHERE" is processed before the "SELECT".

Comment: @bermzkastral This is a pretty good explanation of how SQL processes a query. >> https://dzone.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sqlnbspoper